# mapbox api Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLayer' of undefined when clicking the map - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I setup mapbox just like this in the return of my functional component in reactjs:

```
             <Map
                style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
                containerStyle={{
                    height: '400px',
                    width: '600px'
                }}
                center={[126.216043,6.951969]}
                onClick={(map,evt) => {
                    setMyLocation(evt?.lngLat)
                }}
                >
                <Layer type="symbol" id="marker" layout={{ 'icon-image': 'marker-15' }}>
                    <Feature coordinates={[126.216043,6.951969]} />
                </Layer>
            </Map>
```

I use useState like this:

```
const [mylocation, setMyLocation] = useState({})
```

But everytime I click on the map, I'm getting undefined getLayer
[image]

But if I use `console.log(evt?.lngLat)` it works. Been working on this for hours now.

Comment: are you able to see the marker on the map ?

Comment: no, I don't see any marker.

Comment: then you need to debug why the layer is not being rendered, that would fix your issue

Comment: might try different layer other then marker

Comment: I tried other market but same ressult